# 12.04 doesn't recocognize WIFI on Acer Extensa 5620Z

Tags: wireless

i have a acer extensa 5620z laptop and after installing 12.04 i noticed that it doesn't recognize it's wifi chipset (Intel® Wireless WiFi Link 4965AGN) . Do i need to install additional drivers ? if yes where i can find them ?

Answer (score 1):

disable the preinstalled driver and

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

http://www.linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#Supported_devices